# What privileges does a MySQL user need in order to access FLUSH LOGS?

Tags: mysql, privileges, logrotate, log-rotation

I want o create a new MySQL user for `logrotate` and it needs to be able to run `FLUSH LOGS`, but doesn't need any other privileges as far as I can tell.

What is the minimum mysql privileges I need to give to this user in order to access `FLUSH LOGS` ?

I am using `Mysql 5.7.29` if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `Mysql 5.7.x` docs for the `FLUSH` statement, you would need `RELOAD` privilege.

`RELOAD` privilege docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_reload

`FLUSH` statement docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flush.html